# Extracting Confidence Intervals data.table

Tags: r, data.table, confidence-interval

What I want to do is to have columns for the upper and lower confidence interval for a proportion.

Here is what I have done:

```
> #Create some sample data
> Frustration <- data.table(group = c('A','B','C'), trials = c(363,1398,139), surg = c(57,276,18))
> Frustration
   group trials surg
1:     A    363   57
2:     B   1398  276
3:     C    139   18
> 
> #try to get confidence levels. what I am expecting is CI to be a list of 2 elements, for each value of group, but I don't think that is working
> F2 <- Frustration[, .(CI = prop.test(surg, trials, conf.level = .75)['conf.int']), by = .(group)]
> F2
   group                    CI
1:     A   0.1350140,0.1816828
2:     B   0.1851178,0.2103210
3:     C 0.09701967,0.16972056
> 
> #lower is still a list here - I am stumped
> F3 <- F2[, .(lower = CI[[1]]), by = .(group)]
> F3
   group                 lower
1:     A   0.1350140,0.1816828
2:     B   0.1851178,0.2103210
3:     C 0.09701967,0.16972056
```

I think by confusion has to do with lists, and how data table handles the return.

Thanks for your help,

David

Answer (score 3):

The `CI` is a `list` column.  We can use `transpose` and assign (`:=`)

```
library(data.table)
F2[, c('lower', 'upper') := data.table::transpose(CI)][, CI := NULL][]
#Key: <group>
#    group      lower     upper
#   <char>      <num>     <num>
#1:      A 0.13501400 0.1816828
#2:      B 0.18511780 0.2103210
#3:      C 0.09701967 0.1697206
```

Comment: That's the func I was looking for, `transpose`

Comment: So this works, but I don't understand. My thinking, which is not correct, is that for each group, CI would be separate 2 element list, so taking the first element for lower would work. A transpose implies that for each group, the CI is something else, but what?

Comment: @DavidF You could print the `F2$CI` which is a `list` column with two elements each in each of the list element.  `data.table::transpose(F2$CI)` changes the length of the `list` by concatenating each corresponding element of the list to a vector i.e. first element of each list element is formed of a single vector, simiarly the second element i.e. the lower and upper components are regrouped as two vectors in a new list

Answer (score 2):

The other solution works, but here's a simple one-liner:

```r
library(data.table)

Frustration <- data.table(group = c('A','B','C'), trials = c(363,1398,139),
                          surg = c(57,276,18))

Frustration[, c("lower", "upper") := 
              as.list(prop.test(surg, trials, conf.level = .75)$conf.int), 
            by=group][]
#>    group trials surg      lower     upper
#> 1:     A    363   57 0.13501400 0.1816828
#> 2:     B   1398  276 0.18511780 0.2103210
#> 3:     C    139   18 0.09701967 0.1697206
```

And even simpler, but you'll have to do some renaming:

```r
Frustration[, as.list(prop.test(surg, trials, conf.level = .75)$conf.int), by=group]
#>    group         V1        V2
#> 1:     A 0.13501400 0.1816828
#> 2:     B 0.18511780 0.2103210
#> 3:     C 0.09701967 0.1697206
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes more sense to me, but I still am struggling with the as.list. Doesn't prop.test return a list of lists? When I try Frustration[, prop.test(surg, trials, conf.level = .75)['conf.int'], by=group]
I get 8 rows, as opposed to your 4. i think this is why the transpose is needed in solution 1, but I'm still confused. Thanks.

Comment: No, if you do `class(prop.test(2, 10)$confint)` you'll see that it returns a numeric vector of length 2. By wrapping it in `as.list`, I converted it to a list with two elements, each of which is a single numeric value. `data.table` sees a list, and interprets each element of that list as a column. Since each column only has 1 element, you get 1 row. In contrast, your call includes a single element (a vector of length 2), so `data.table` interprets this as you asking for 1 column with 2 rows.